# Find out how an Android app controls my AV Receiver

Tags: android, networking

I have an Onkyo Audio Receiver (AR), and there is an Android app that I can use to control it, change the volume, the channel etc. As a little project at home, I'm working on an app that can control certain functions on my computer.

I'd like to add the same functionality with my receiver into my app, purely as a technical challenge to myself. I know what IP the AR is assigned to (192.168.0.2), but I don't know how the app controls it.

Are there any beginning tips on what I can do to figure out how this app works?

The receiver model is TX-NR515, and the app is called OnkyoRemote.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by tracing all the traffic coming in and out of your application. A good summary of ways to do that are well documented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555403/capturing-mobile-phone-traffic-on-wireshark) stack overflow answer ().

Once you capture the traffic, examine it, what type of protocol does it use? Chances are, it's something wireshark will recognize, like http.

The next step I'd try is to examine what traffic is generated per each component in your app, for example, start the capture, press only the up command, than examine the traffic to identify the exact command on the wire

Comment: Thanks for that link, I'll give a few of those suggestions a go. I've also managed to decompile the apk file, so hopefully with capturing traffic, and the source I should be able to figure this out.

Comment: It will be interesting to hear what you dig out and how you did it. Every reverse engineer has a quirk on how to examine things and it will benefit further readers to learn about a different approach. Anyhow, good luck!

Comment: Well if I manage to get any headway with this I'll update here to show what method I ended up using.

Comment: Very interested in this, as well! Please post any developments or progress.

Comment: I had to do some digging myself as this was interesting. I did not trace the traffic, but after decompiling the apk, it is obvious the whole thing relies on upnp. If you have a working setup, try capturing the upnp data that is transmitted from the device using the approach from my answer (I can only test the outgoing requests as I use a Denon receiver (;)

Comment: I'm trying to capture the data now, but I'm having some issues with Wireshark (first time using it). My phone has the ip 192.168.0.4, and the AR 192.168.0.2. When I put the filter as `ip.src==192.168.0.4 and ip.dst==192.168.0.2`, I get a load of other results back, nothing to do with those IP's. Is the what Wireshark should do, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your filter should look exactly like this: (ip.dst==192.168.0.2) && (ip.src==192.168.0.4). If the expression is valid, the filter textbox should have a green background. Is that what you tried?

Comment: I didn't use the brackets, I'm at work at the moment, but I'll give that a try when I get back in, thanks!

Comment: Using the filters I couldn't get anything captured. I tried as you put above, and also tried just `udp.port==1900`, and all I got was my AR sending NOFITY messages out.

Comment: Try running the app in an emulator, and run wireshark on the computer hosting the emulator. You may have a problem capturing packets from your phone. If you clear the filter, do you see anything the phone sends/receives?